# VBA Excel Adding Range With Dynamic Size To Combobox List

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a range within the workbook that I'd like to set to the list of items in a Combobox from one of my Userforms. The issue is the Range can be any size. I currently handle the zero case by exiting the `Sub`, but when there's only one element in the range.

When there's one element, instead of returning an array of elements, it only returns a single `String` element and the listbox gives me an error:
`Run-time error '381': Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index'. Is there anyway to handle this besides creating an exception for the case where there's only one element?

Here's the code:
Edit: Fixed program to accurately represent problem.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim formList As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = getLastRowInCol(Sheets("HiddenVariables"), "B")
    If lastRow = 0 Or lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub 
    formList = Sheets("HiddenVariables").Range("B2:B" & lastRow).value 'If lastRow =2 then run-time error 381 is thrown
    Me.ComboBox.list = formList
End Sub
```

[image: Same issue with solution]

Comment: Comparison operators are a single `=` in VBA, not a double `==`. False is also considered zero so `If Not CBool(lastRow) Then Exit Sub` is also appropriate.

Comment: Right, fixed that. Thanks

Comment: You might try inserting `If Not IsArray(formList) Then formList = Array(formList)` before `Me.ComboBox.list = formList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use named range and `RowSource` property of combobox.

Define a named range :

[image]

Then simply set the rowsource

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!Combo_Source"
End Sub
```

Going by your approach, use this:

```
If IsArray(formList) Then
        Me.ComboBox1.List = formList
     Else
        Me.ComboBox1.List = Split(formList, "") '/Converts str to arr on the fly.
   End If
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think you can also just use `Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!B2:B" & lastRow`. Which actually solves my problem completely. Thank you, I've been struggling with this for too long.